# React router v6: Protected Routes displaying after logging out

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to implement a private route in React; the homepage should not be visible until the user logs in. If I restart my frontend, all protected routes are not accessible until the user logs in. However, after the first login, all protected routes don't seem to be protected; I can logout, the session is destroyed in my database and my backend sends a response of {isLoggedIn: false}, but for some reason I can still access the protected routes.

When I didn't use 'useState', I could login and my backend would confirm I was logged in, but I still couldn't access any protected routes. This is the closest I've got to my end goal, but obviously still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

## Private Routes

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const checkIfLogged = async () => {

    let[logged, setLogged] = useState(false);

    await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/auth", { 
        withCredentials: true
    }).then((res) => {
        setLogged(res.data.isLoggedIn);
    })
    return logged;
}

const updateAuth = async(check) => {
    const loggedIn = await check;
    return loggedIn;
}

const PrivateRoutes = () =>{
    const loggedIn = updateAuth(checkIfLogged);

    return(
         loggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
    )
}

export default PrivateRoutes;
```

## Auth Check

```
app.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.isAuth){
        res.send({isLoggedIn: true})
    }
    else{
        res.send({isLoggedIn: false})
    }
})
```

## App.js

```
import{
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

import React from "react";

import Home from "./screens/Home";
import About from "./screens/About";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import Register from "./screens/Register";
import Logout from "./screens/Logout";
import PrivateRoutes from "./utils/private";

const App = () => {
  return (
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes/>}>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />}/>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}/>
          <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />}/>
        </Routes>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is by actually make a conditional rendering based on if the user is admin, then the page is rendered, otherwise a `null` is returned:

so in your PrivateRoutes:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const PrivateRoute = async () => {

    let[logged, setLogged] = useState(false);
    let [isSuperUser,setIsSuperUser] = useState(false) // adding new state

    useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/auth", { 
        withCredentials: true
    }).then((res) => {
        setLogged(res.data.isLoggedIn);
        setIsSuperUser(res.data.isSuperUser)
    })
},[isLoggedIn]) 
    return (
          isLoggedIn&& isSuperUser?<Outlet/>:null
)


}


export default PrivateRoutes;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm still encountering an issue that I can't seem to resolve; in this case, null is always returned since the values of logged and isSuperUser don't seem to change (I have checked, the server definitely returns true if the user is logged in / is an admin, but the state does not update).

Comment: Aha, I've found a fix, all is good now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: upvote this and accept the answer if you think it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this solution is valid, however, I added a 2nd solution that match the OP style.

First of all, `checkLoggedIn` is a component, so it need to be capitalized, fix it to `CheckLoggedIn`

Second of all, I am not sure what backend you are using, but I would check if the user is an admin/superuser all in App.js, since we are dealing with routes here, and then based on that I will let them access the protected route:

in App.js

```
import{
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

import React from "react";

import {useEffect,useState} from React;
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import About from "./screens/About";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import Register from "./screens/Register";
import Logout from "./screens/Logout";
import PrivateRoutes from "./utils/private";

const App = () => {
  let[logged, setLogged] = useState(false)
   let [isSuperUser,setIsSuperUser] = useState(false)
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('localhost:3001/auth/',{withCredentials:true}).then((res)=>{
      // send a response if the current logged in user is a super user
      setLogged(res.data.isLoggedIn)
      setIsSuperUser(res.data.isSuperUser)
}
},[logged]) // useEffect will get re-invoked whenever the user log out, or their session is ended

// now for the last part, I would make a conditional rendering, where a user will access route only if they are superuser/admin
  return (
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={isSuperUser?<PrivateRoutes/>:''}>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />}/>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}/>
          <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />}/>
        </Routes>
      </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Notice the first route, you will only be able to access it if you are a logged in admin.

you also need to notice that what define a react component is 2 things:

1. Capitalization of your functional component name
2. it has to return a JSX